# Deleting table rows in Excel VBA by cell value - doesn't delete all rows, why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-2019

I created this macro in Excel 2016, and the problem persists in Excel 2019.

My spreadsheet has a macro to delete all rows in which a cell in a specific column contains the word 'Closed'. The macro mostly works but 2-3 of the rows still remain. Running the macro a second time will clear them.

Am I making things harder by looking up the column number by the text in its header? I probably could hard-code it; I just wanted to make it futureproof in case I want to move that column later.

Macro:

```
Sub RemoveClosed()

' Select table
    Dim rObj As ListObject
    Set rObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable")

' Clear any applied filters
    On Error Resume Next 'If filters are already cleared, don't throw a wobbly
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' Recalculate all formulas
    Application.Calculate 
    
' Get the column number of the 'Closure' column
    Dim closureCol As Long
    closureCol = rObj.HeaderRowRange.Find("Closure").Column

' Specify what we're going to look for and use as deletion criteria
    Dim lookupValue As String
    lookupValue = "Closed"

' Start a counter for the If loop
    Dim zed As Integer

' If loop:
        For zed = 1 To rObj.ListRows.Count                      ' Counter cycles from 1 to total number of data rows

            If Cells(zed, closureCol).Value = lookupValue Then  ' If cell in Closure column in row 'zed' contains the deletion criterion
                
                If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
                    DoEvents
                End If
                Rows(zed).EntireRow.Delete                      ' Delete entire row
            End If

        Next zed

End Sub
```

Comment: Do `For zed = rObj.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1` instead - I am sure you can find a ton of similar Q&As both here and on Stack Overflow.